# Encoding problems while exporting from revit 2016 in ifc

Tags: python, error

I'm currently working on a project in Revit. I decided to make some visualization in blender and exported my model in .ifc format.

I'm working with Russian language in Revit, so after exporting, all walls are named in russian. The problem is that there are symbols which are non-unicode:

[image: encoding]

I marked by yellow the incorrect symbol.

The problem is that when I'm trying to use some python scripts, for example this:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    print(ob.name)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 58: 
invalid continuation byte
```

I get an error working with this objects/materials/textures etc. Exporting from revit to fbx gives the same result.

I understand that it is better to use English verison of Revit for exporting, but maybe there is a solution which doesn't require changing language?

Is there any way to delete the incorrect symbols using some python script? I don't need to "recover" them - just ignoring would be OK :)

Comment: Lesson to learn: Always use ASCI names in important digital data. Is IFC in binary or plain text format? If in plaintext use a basic plain text editor to find and replace the offending characters.

Comment: Hi! It's the settings of exporting in Revit, I just can't change them.

Comment: By the way, IFC is plain text, but the text is encoded :) but still, I can try to write some python script to change them, thanks for idea :)